# Why is requests using GET after I tell it to POST?

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm not even sure if this is happening, it may be something on URLScan.io's end but using the following code:

```
api = '####################'
url = 'https://www.urlscan.io/api/v1/scan/'

headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'API-key': api
}

data = '{"url": "https://www.google.com", "public": "on"}'

resp = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=headers)
```

I keep getting the following error:

```
{
  "message": "Wrong method, use POST",
  "description": "In order to scan a page, you have to POST here.",
  "status": 405
}
```

I have no clue what I'm doing wrong. In my debugger, it says that even though I call requests.post resp is a requests.get return object. How could that even be possible? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It is not daid that this is not POST, it is not because the error gives a certain error, that that error is completely correct. IIt is for example possible that each time the request is invalid, it returns such error.

Comment: Check to see if you are getting a redirect.  If so, include that information.

Comment: When I attempt to hit the url, I'm redirected to a similar url without the www at the front.  Try removing `www.` from the url and trying again.

Comment: Nope, no redirect. In the information about the requests object it says `is_redirect: False`

Comment: That's because you have it set to follow redirects automatically. The final response isn't a redirect.

Comment: @Larry Lustig you nailed it. I can't believe I didn't notice that >>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run this on the command line:

```
curl -X POST "https://urlscan.io/api/v1/scan/" \
    -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
    -H "API-Key: $apikey" \
    -d "{\"url\": \"$url\", \"public\": \"on\"}"
```

If you get same message back, then it has something to do with them likely.

Comment: This works, but only because you omitted the www. It works perfectly without it in requests as well. Can't believe I missed that! I guess this counts as an answer

Comment: If you're going to be testing a lot of HTTP endpoints, I really like [httpie](https://httpie.org/).

Answer (score 3):

Except that data should be a dict, not a preformatted json string, you're not doing anything wrong.

```
r = requests.post('https://httpbin.org/post', data = {'key':'value'})
```

[Reference](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/)

Answer (score 0):

Hey following is the code that work for urlscan.io in python:

```
import requests
import json

headers = {'API-Key':'your-api-key','Content-Type': 'application/json'}
params = {'url': 'scan-url' }
response = requests.post('https://urlscan.io/api/v1/scan/',headers=headers, data=json.dumps(params))
```

The response to the API call will give you the scan ID and API endpoint for the scan, you can use it to retrieve the result after waiting for a short while. Until the scan is finished, the URL will respond with a HTTP 404 status code.

Hope it helps!!